# Why does jQuery(document).on('click... not register a click on specific divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On click of anywhere on the document, I'd like to make sure I close my menus. I am running a console log on document click, and do not see it populate when clicking on specific divs.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', function(e){
     console.log('- - - - clicking the document - - - -');
});
```

I am expecting to see this console log if I click anywhere on the page. Any help is much appreciated. I feel as though I am missing something here. Why would the console log not populate whenever I click on a specific div, but populates everywhere else.

```
<div id="info-201972681835185" class="panelInfoBox compareViewInfo" style="bottom: 30px; right: 0px;" previewid="201972681835185" processid="201972681835185">      
    <form id="photoInfoForm-201972681835185">
        <input name="externalApprovalStateId" id="externalApprovalStateId" value="1000" type="hidden" class="">            
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" title="Label" value="2" class="processEdit title" placeholder="Label">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: without some html we are supposed to guess. Any chance to show us a simplifed html that can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The divs where you don't see it happen either have their own click handler that stops event propagation, or are within another element that has such a click handler. For a click to reach `document`, it has to be allowed to propagate.

Here's an example:

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', function(e){
     console.log('- - - - clicking the document - - - -');
});
jQuery(".div2").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
jQuery("section").on("click", function() {
    // This does both stopPropagation and preventDefault
    return false;
});
```

```css
.div1, .div2, .section1 div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
  padding 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  This is div #1, clicks will register
</div>
<div class="div2">
  This is div #2, clicks won't register because it has a click handler that stops propagation
</div>
<section class="section1">
  <div>
    This is div #3, clicks won't register because it's inside an element that has a click handler that stops propagation
  </div>
</section>
<div id="info-201972681835185" class="panelInfoBox compareViewInfo" style="bottom: 30px; right: 0px;" previewid="201972681835185" processid="201972681835185">      
    <form id="photoInfoForm-201972681835185">
        <input name="externalApprovalStateId" id="externalApprovalStateId" value="1000" type="hidden" class="">            
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" title="Label" value="2" class="processEdit title" placeholder="Label">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In a comment you said:

> What's interesting is I am seeing that the div that doesn't register the click is dynamically added via js at a later time. So I tried to run the jQuery(document) click again afterwards, but it still didn't register. The div is simply an info panel that is dynamically added via js and slides out when a button is clicked.

It doesn't matter when the `div` was added, it still follows the rule above. For instance, here's the earlier example but with your `div` added after 800ms:

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', function(e){
     console.log('- - - - clicking the document - - - -');
});
jQuery(".div2").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
jQuery("section").on("click", function() {
    // This does both stopPropagation and preventDefault
    return false;
});
setTimeout(function() {
    $(`<div id="info-201972681835185" class="panelInfoBox compareViewInfo" style="bottom: 30px; right: 0px;" previewid="201972681835185" processid="201972681835185">      
    <form id="photoInfoForm-201972681835185">
        <input name="externalApprovalStateId" id="externalApprovalStateId" value="1000" type="hidden" class="">            
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" title="Label" value="2" class="processEdit title" placeholder="Label">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>`).appendTo(document.body);
}, 800);
```

```css
.div1, .div2, .section1 div, .div4 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
  padding 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  This is div #1, clicks will register
</div>
<div class="div2">
  This is div #2, clicks won't register because it has a click handler that stops propagation
</div>
<section class="section1">
  <div>
    This is div #3, clicks won't register because it's inside an element that has a click handler that stops propagation
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Clicking that fourth div still triggers the handler. This is the central aspect of delegated event handling.

Comment: What's interesting is I am seeing that the div that doesn't register the click is dynamically added via js at a later time. So I tried to run the jQuery(document) click again afterwards, but it still didn't register. The div is simply an info panel that is dynamically added via js and slides out when a button is clicked.

Comment: @jmchauv - I've updated the answer to address that. Briefly: It doesn't matter that the div was added later.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I still seem to be having issues though. In theory, shouldn't I be able to run jQuery('#info-201972681835185').off('click') and jQuery('#info-201972681835185').children().off('click'); in order to remove any event handlers on the div, resulting in the console log showing after these have been run? Or am I mistaken? From what I can tell, there are no event handlers on this main div.

Comment: @jmchauv - That will only remove handlers installed via jQuery, not ones installed using the DOM directly. Also, if the handler is on the element the div is being added to (or an ancestor of that element), removing handlers from the element and its **children** won't affect that. You'd have to remove handlers from its *ancestor* elements.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. There was a click event on the parent.